# Stellar validator node

Tags: stellar-core, validators

My question is about running a stellar validator node.
Why Starting stellar-core in FORCE_SCP mode requires NODE_IS_VALIDATOR to be set?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> If you don’t include a `NODE_SEED` or set `NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true`, you will still watch SCP and see all the data in the network but will not send validation messages.

https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/admin.html

Does that help?